# Handlebars java - quotes in helper

Tags: java, handlebars.js, mustache

I am using jknack handlebars.java v4.2.0

I want to include a field in my template if that field is not empty and I want that field to be wrapped in double quotes.

e.g.

```
You have received a payment. "Food expenses"
```

or if the reference wasn't provided:

```
You have received a payment.
```

I tried to write a custom helper for this:

```
@SneakyThrows
public CharSequence formattedPaymentReference(String paymentReference) {
    return isEmpty(paymentReference) ? Strings.EMPTY : String.format("\"%s\"", paymentReference);
}
```

And then update my template:

```
You have received a payment. {{formattedPaymentReference reference}}
```

But the output is not what I need, it isn't using the actual quotation marks.

```
You have received a payment. &quot;Food expenses&quot;
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: https://jknack.github.io/handlebars.java/helpers.html See the "Helper Return Value" section. The docs are your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@SneakyThrows
public CharSequence formattedPaymentReference(String paymentReference) {
    return isEmpty(paymentReference) ? Strings.EMPTY : new SafeString(String.format("\"%s\"", paymentReference));
}
```

Used Handlebars.SafeString to unescape the quotes.